# How to know if the map scale is set by a data defined expression using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Using PyQGIS, I can find the scale of a QgsLayoutItemMap using `layoutMapItem.scale()` or by quering the value of the variable `map_scale`.

The following code snip finds out the current selected (layout item) *map scale* on the first layout, as expected:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
layout = projectLayoutManager.layouts()[0]
print(layout.name())
layoutMapItem = layout.selectedLayoutItems()[0]
print(layoutMapItem.id())
print(layoutMapItem.scale())
context = layoutMapItem.createExpressionContext()
print(context.variable('map_scale'))
```

```
exec(Path('/tmp/tmp7fkcqm0a').read_text())
puce_ploc
Mapa 5
1999.9999999999998
1999.9999999999998
```

I want to know if this scale value results from a data defined value or not.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the three following statements:

- Is there an expression set for the scale?
- Is it active?
- Is the result of the expression equal to the current value set as the scale (not manually overridden)?

```py
import math 

project = QgsProject.instance()
project_layout_manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = project_layout_manager.layouts()[0]
layout_map_item = layout.selectedLayoutItems()[0]

# Get scale property
layout_map_item_properties = layout_map_item.dataDefinedProperties()
scale_property_index = QgsLayoutObject.DataDefinedProperty.MapScale
scale_property = layout_map_item_properties.property(scale_property_index)

# Check if the property is set and active
if scale_property and scale_property.isActive():
    expression_value = scale_property.value(project.createExpressionContext())[0]
    actual_value = layout_map_item.scale()
    
    # Check if the result of the expression is equal to the current value of the property
    # If false, it means that the value was manually overridden
    is_data_derived_value = math.isclose(expression_value, actual_value)
else:
    is_data_derived_value = False

print(is_data_derived_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out if the scale comes from a data defined value, one has to use `layoutMapItem.dataDefinedProperties()`.

```
if (QgsLayoutObject.MapScale in layoutMapItem.dataDefinedProperties().propertyKeys()):
    if layoutMapItem.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.MapScale).isActive():
        print('scale is data defined')
```

Comment: Be careful, this doesn't check if the expression is active or that the value hasn't been overridden. Just that an expression is set.

Comment: Nice catch @Kalak. I've updated the answer based on your comment.